# CSS IE Dropdown expanding onclick fix

Tags: jquery, css

SO I found this fix for a drop down expanding in IE when clicked

```
if ($j.browser.msie && $j.browser.version < 9)
    $j("#partDropdown,#categoryDropdown")
        .live("focus mouseover", function() { $j(this).addClass('expand').removeClass('clicked'); })
        .live('click', function() { $j(this).toggleClass('clicked'); })
        .live('mouseout', function() {
            if (!$j(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
                $j(this).removeClass('expand');
            }
        })
        .live('blur', function() { $j(this).removeClass('expand clicked'); });
```

Which had the following css also

```
.expand select
{
    width: auto !important;
}
```

But never had a css for clicked ? Is it needed ? or does the jquery just add a empty class of clicked ?

Comment: did it work that way? Go try and test it, and if it doesn't add that clicked class, and if this doesn't work too, come back and ask an actual question.

Comment: Yeah it work I was just wondering why it worked without him adding the clicked css class

Comment: Or if I needed to add my own css clicked class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clicked`-class is there to prevent collapsing when "mouse-outing" after you performed a click on that element:

```
if (!$j(this).hasClass('clicked')){...}
```

That's all you need this class for. You don't have to specify any rules for this class in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS classes that aren't defined in any CSS file or `<style>` tag, they just won't change how the tag is rendered.

It's actually a very common practice to attach meta-data to your tags since they're easy to add and remove, and trivial to query (you can use select expressions in jQuery and the like for example). In this case, the `clicked` class is used to retain whether or not the dropdown has been clicked, which otherwise would require messy global variables (or tricky lambda functions).